# Removable FireWire port blocks

Tags: physical

There are other questions here enquiring about disabling FireWire ports [reversibly via software](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4098/10198) or [irreversibly via hardware (e.g. epoxy/desoldering)](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/17051/10198).

I would like to know if there are any reversible *hardware* protection methods available; for instance, something similar to these USB port (b)locks: [1](https://www.kensington.com/kensington/en/gb/s/1645/usb-locks.aspx) [2](http://www.lindy.co.uk/usb-port-blocker-pack-of-4-colour-code-blue/40452.html).

Comment: At my company, we prepare all new machines that have firewire by filling the ports with epoxy.

Answer (score 2):

At a cleared defense contractor we actually looked at building these and it is not that hard of an issue. Not foolproof, but fairly reasonable. It was a cyber-security research program and it did not get funding, but I always thought it would be a great commercial idea. At the time (a couple of years ago), to my knowledge, no one was doing this for firewire. Not many for USB, but it looks like the USB market has changed.

Comment: Any chance you could open-source the CAD files/etc that your project generated, so that other people might be able to benefit from your research? It would be great to be able to 3D-print a FireWire port block - or at least for someone to start manufacturing them for a reasonable price.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I was with another company at the time...